# Get request headers in selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the request headers after login to specific website, I tried this approach but got empty result

```
Dim headers As String
headers = .ExecuteScript("var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); " & _
                               "req.open('GET', document.location, true); " & _
                               "req.send(null); " & _
                               "req.onload = function() { " & _
                               "    var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase(); " & _
                               "    return headers; " & _
                               "};")
Debug.Print headers
```

I tried the following

```
headers = .ExecuteScript("var req = new XMLHttpRequest();req.open('GET', document.location, false);req.send(null);return req.getAllResponseHeaders()")
```

and I got this

```
accept-ranges: bytes
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 2115
content-type: text/html
date: Sat, 09 Mar 2024 08:41:29 GMT
etag: "80a7aa20f76bda1:0"
```

but this is not the request headers I am trying to get.
Any help regarding this topic.

Comment: perhaps switch to python + selenium wire

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-capture-http-requests-using-selenium-ash-sheng/

Comment: @QHarr. I have special code that I would like to share with you.